# What is the max level in Mario Golf GBC?

Tags: mario-golf-gbc

What is the maximum level for custom characters in Mario Golf for Game Boy Color?

Comment: [This article](https://themushroomkingdom.net/board/index.php?topic=13265.0) suggests its level 99 however it doesnt add definitive proof that its the max level. [This other article](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/197858-mario-golf/59327952) also suggests the same thing however once again its not an official source so I cant say 99 is the correct answer.